# Android studio: Is there any way to have fewer xml files?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

Basically my app contains of lots and lots of buttons. And it will continue to grow a few more hundred. So basically right now I have to link one button each to its own .xml and .class to make one each button to show a different page.

Is there a way to have one huge file containing every button id to create a unique page?

Let's say every button contains an animal picture, its name and information about it, but every animal is different (Basically the layout is the exact same except other picture, name and info.)

Comment: create a custom button, pass a string id to a custom function inside the custom button class for the activity you want it to go to, e.g. customButton.display(ACTIVITY_LOCATION); and inside that function put the intent you would like inside a switch statement based on the ID passed to the method.

Comment: Why don't use listview / gridview / recyler view?